# How to change range of years in twig

Tags: symfony, twig

This is my Formtype

```
->add('dateNaissance', 'date', array(
    'required' => true, 
    'widget' => 'choice', 
    'years' => range(date('Y') - 100, date('Y') ),
))
->add('type', 'hidden', array( 
    'mapped' => false, 
));
```

and i fixed my range like this but i want to get  3 different range in  my formwidget older, younger and baby it is possible to change range in form_widget ?

For example can i give a parameter here to change my range

```
{{ form_widget(adulte.dateNaissance.year,
    {'attr': {
        'class': 'form-control pull-left birthdate-y-coordonnees'
    }}
)}}
```

Comment: The simple is do it in  `FormType`. In Symfony doc have example: `How to dynamically Generate Forms Based on user Data` http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#how-to-dynamically-generate-forms-based-on-user-data

Comment: What do you mean 3 different ranges?